# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pmss.Login

Tags: java, android

This is my SplashScreen class

```
package com.pmss;
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                    Intent splash = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(splash);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }
}
```

And This is my Login class

```
package com.pmss;


    public class Login extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button login, register;
    private EditText email, password;

    JSONArray loginposition = null;
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://XXX.XXX.X.XX/PMSS/login.php";

    // JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_POSITION = "position";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerlauncher);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.useridlogin);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordlogin);

//      SharedPreferences userDetails =getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
//        Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
//        edit.clear();
//        edit.putString("email", "");
//        edit.putString("password", "");
//        edit.commit();

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Username = email.getText().toString();
                String Password = password.getText().toString();
                new AttemptLogin(Username, Password).execute();
            }
        });

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // For the main activity, make sure the app icon in the action bar
            // does not behave as a button
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

//  public void onBackPressed() {
//      Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
//      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//      intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
//      startActivity(intent);
//      finish();
//  }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        /*
         * case R.id.login: new AttemptLogin().execute(); break; case
         * R.id.register: Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
         * startActivity(i); break;
         */
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {

        private final String TAG = null;
        boolean failure = false;
        String res;
        String Username, Password,Email,Position;
        String CompareUser = "user", CompareStaff = "staff";
        int success;

        public AttemptLogin(String Username, String Password) {
            this.Username = Username;
            this.Password = Password;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);
                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                res = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                if(success == 1){
                loginposition = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
                    // // looping through all posts according to the json object
                    // // returned
                    for (int i = 0; i < loginposition.length(); i++) {
                        // String jsonText = loginposition.getString(i);
                        JSONObject c = loginposition.getJSONObject(i);
                        // gets the content of each tag
                        // String content = c.getString(TAG_USERID);
                        Email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        Position = c.getString(TAG_POSITION);

                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "JSON error", e);
                success = Integer.valueOf(0);
            }
            return success;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if (success != null && success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", "res: " + res);
                // save user data
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("email", Email);
                edit.putString("position", Position);
                edit.commit();
                if (Position.equals(CompareUser)) {
                    Intent usermenu = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(usermenu);
                }
                else if (Position.equals(CompareStaff)) {
                    Intent staffmenu = new Intent(Login.this,
                            StaffMainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(staffmenu);
                }
                Toast.makeText(
                        Login.this,
                        res == null ? "Please enter both user id and password  (success)"
                                : res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                email.setText(null);
                password.setText(null);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", "res: " + res);
                Toast.makeText(
                        Login.this,
                        res == null ? "Please enter both user id and password  (failed)"
                                : res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is my logcat

```
03-17 14:34:37.333: W/dalvikvm(21719): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/pmss/Login; (23)
03-17 14:34:37.333: W/dalvikvm(21719): Link of class 'Lcom/pmss/Login;' failed
03-17 14:34:37.333: E/dalvikvm(21719): Could not find class 'com.pmss.Login', referenced from method com.pmss.SplashScreen$1.run
03-17 14:34:37.333: W/dalvikvm(21719): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 69 (Lcom/pmss/Login;) in Lcom/pmss/SplashScreen$1;
03-17 14:34:37.333: D/dalvikvm(21719): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0009
03-17 14:34:37.373: I/Adreno-EGL(21719): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
03-17 14:34:37.393: D/OpenGLRenderer(21719): Enabling debug mode 0
03-17 14:34:39.363: W/dalvikvm(21719): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41548ba8)
03-17 14:34:39.363: E/AndroidRuntime(21719): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-39807
03-17 14:34:39.363: E/AndroidRuntime(21719): Process: com.pmss, PID: 21719
03-17 14:34:39.363: E/AndroidRuntime(21719): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pmss.Login
03-17 14:34:39.363: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at com.pmss.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:19)
```

I do't know why my program said the SplashScreen class can't found Login class when I already have this Login class. Last time I install this in my Galaxy Ace with 2.3.2 Gingerbread and now I'm using Nexus 5 with 4.4.2 and it stuck here.

SplashScreen.java line 19:

```
Intent splash = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
```

This is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pmss"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_main" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.Register"
        android:label="@string/button_register"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Login" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.Login" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Login" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.Login" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.UserInfo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_info"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.MainMenu" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.MainMenu" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.Payment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_payment"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.MainMenu" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.MainMenu" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.TrackParcel"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_track_parcel"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.MainMenu" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.MainMenu" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.CheckCard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_check_card"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.MainMenu" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.MainMenu" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.RequestService"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_request_service"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.MainMenu" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.MainMenu" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Login" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.Login" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.StaffInfo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_staff_info"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.FulfillRequest"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fulfill_request"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.OnlinePayment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_online_payment"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Payment" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.Payment" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.CardPayment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_card_payment"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Payment" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.Payment" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.CashPayment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cash_payment"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Payment" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.Payment" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pmss.StaffTrackParcel"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_staff_track_parcel"
        android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post the manifest file

Comment: `Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/pmss/Login;` meaning `ActionBarActivity` is unknown

Comment: oh.. Even though I already import my support library and yet ActionBarActivity?

Comment: Raghunandan I already posted my Manifest file